# PHP Soap Client receives incomplete data

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I wrote very simple code to retrieve soap data:

```
    $wsdl = 'https://...';
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, ['trace' => true]);

    $soap_parameters = [
        'leveranciernaam' => 'xxx',
        'leveranciersleutel' => 'yyy',
        'brinnummer' => 'zzzz',
        'schooljaar' => 2012
    ];

    $response = $client->getLeerlingen($soap_parameters);
```

To my huge surprise, the return was different from the return i received while using a Java based GUI application. 
Some fields in PHP SoapClient's response were consistently missing.

Just to make sure that things were not lost in translation to stdObjects, I used `trace` option to and extracted actual XMl from `$client->__getLastResponse();`
Still those fields were not there - very consistently over hundreds of records.

Windows Java based client's response:

```
<return>
    <leerlingen>
        <leerling>
            <id>353226866</id>
            <roepnaam>Evline</roepnaam>
            ...  
            <achternaam>Staalstra</achternaam>
            <inschrijvingen>
                <inschrijving>
                    <id>353226867</id>
                    <datumInschrijving>2007-08-20T00:00:00+02:00</datumInschrijving>
                    <schoolVanHerkomst>7138</schoolVanHerkomst>
                    <vervolgSchool>7138</vervolgSchool>
                    <onderwijsSoortBestemming>
                       <id>4085</id>
                   </onderwijsSoortBestemming>
                </inschrijving>
            </inschrijvingen>
        </leerling>
        ...
    </leerlingen>
    <brins>
        <brin>
            <id>47187537</id>
            <brinNummer>02YN02</brinNummer>
            <schoolNaam>De Ambelt School V LZK</schoolNaam>
        </brin>
        ...
    </brins>
</return>
```

Response i get:

```
<return>
    <leerlingen>
        <leerling>
            <id>353226866</id>
            <roepnaam>Evline</roepnaam>
            ...  
            <achternaam>Staalstra</achternaam>
            <inschrijvingen>
                <inschrijving>
                    <id>353226867</id>
                    <datumInschrijving>2007-08-20T00:00:00+02:00</datumInschrijving>
                    <inschrijvingType>1766564</inschrijvingType>
                </inschrijving>
            </inschrijvingen>
        </leerling>
        ...
    </leerlingen>
</return>
```

PHP client does not get (or does not properly parse) any elements `schoolVanHerkomst`, `vervolgSchool` and `onderwijsSoortBestemming` in element `inschrijving` and it misses `brins` completely.

For brevity, I omitted other deeply nested elements that work just fine

Because expected results are dynamic, WDSL ( https://acceptatie.parnassys.net/bao/services/cxf/v1/generic?wsdl ) does not define ouput.

What is going on? It seems that PHP Soap client is less reliable than Java Soap clients

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect imho, but where is the xml? And which fields are missing? And what does the wsdl say? Without answers to these question, I am not able to help you further

Comment: At the time of me writing that comment, the last statement you made was _It seems that PHP Soap client is less reliable than Java Soap clients_

Comment: Please remove any sensitive information from your question... I dont think people like it when you post their information here!

Comment: @RichardBernards You don't need to use that tone. There is no sensitive information - it's fake data.

Comment: BRIN-number checked out... So this leads to the assumption the other data is correct as well ofcourse...

Comment: It could be a number of things. For example, the way you are sending your parameters, the content-encoding on the server/client, etc. It's a shame this isnt a public API or I could help you out some more...

Comment: What other way to send parameters can you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65384/discussion-between-konstantin-and-richardbernards).

Comment: Right now, in 2023, the wsdl URL has a v3 instead of v1... But I am still struggling to get out all data. Do you still have your code from back then and are you willing to share?

Comment: @MarjavanderWind it's been so long ... I don't even remember writing this post :) have you tried asking Chat GPT to help you figure it out?